# How do I use JQuery.support to check if the browser is Firefox?

Tags: jquery

It seems that jQuery.browser is deprecated in the latest jQuery.  The doc recommends that I use jQuery.support. Which of the support tests should I use to check if the current browser is Firefox?

Comment: I wanted to detect Firefox only because I'm trying to find a javascript ellipsis solution. Currently, text-overflow: ellipsis or (Opera's) -o-text-overflow:ellipsis; only show up properly in Chrome, IE and Opera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the point of the 'support' method. You don't check if user is using Firefox or not. You check whether the browser 'supports' whatever DOM manipulation you are trying to do. This is called 'feature detection' which is preferred compared to 'browser detection'(what you are trying to do).

E.g. let's say you want verify whether the browser can render your CSS which contains 'opacity', so you use the jquery.support.opacity property.

So why would you want to do 'feature detection'? Simple, you can write cross browser scripts which are future compatible.

Let's say that you check for 'Firefox' and apply some elaborate DOM/CSS effects. What if the next version of Firefox breaks the particular DOM/CSS feature you were relying on? You will have to go back and update your script. But if you used 'feature detection', your code will be future proof against such changes.

Now, I am not suggesting that you will be able to use 'feature detection' for all your requirements, but put some thought about whether you want to use feature detection or browser detection.

Few more links worth reading:

http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2006/11/16/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection/

Comment: I'm not so sure feature detection makes your app future proof. What if the feature exists but becomes buggy in some way?

Comment: Well, it won't make it 100% foolproof. But the feature detection code will be more resilient compared to the browser detection code.

Comment: Maybe. I'm waiting to see if that's true. I had one case where the flot charting application screwed up on filled charts on Opera only before a certain revision. There was no good way to test for that. I had to explicitly test for Opera and a revision. I think that a lot of people are embracing feature detection with little evidence that it will save them. I think what's more likely is that browsers will work with jQuery BECAUSE jQuery is so popular that it will be well-tested against.

Comment: As I wrote in my original post, it's not possible to use feature detection in all circumstances [e.g. you can't check if browser supports transparent PNGs.] 

And yes, if browser vendors try to support jQuery and if you use jquery.support, you are covered automatically as against if you used jQuery.browser.

Comment: Didn't mean to argue with you. I'm just skeptical about whether feature detection is the future-proofing that people desire. Browser compatibility is tough no matter what. For example, Mobile Safari doesn't return a mousedown message until the mouseup happens. How do you detect that? I think a lot of feature detection is veiled browser detection.

Comment: ok. so do we know that one property for sure, which is so mozilla specific that no one (browser) would have it ever? so that after checking for that, we will know for sure that browser is firefox?

Comment: I want to know if the user has Firefox, so I can point them to the Firefox Extension required.. what "Support" would that be?

Comment: It's easy to give "clever" advice, but it doesn't really help. I also need to detect firefox, but with $.browser deprecated, I'll have to do my own stupid hacks instead.

Comment: From another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1958948 ... though MozBoxShadow doesn't seem to exist, MozBoxAlign (and many others) still do.