# How to detect Firefox using Jquery support?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use JQuery.support to check if the browser is Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088934/how-do-i-use-jquery-support-to-check-if-the-browser-is-firefox)

Hi guys I am trying to detect Firefox browser using Jquery support property but i have no idea how can I accomplish that:( 
I know for example how to detect if browser supports opacity (`jQuery.support.opacity`) but I would like to use something similar for detecting **Firefox only without** using `$.browser` property. 
Thank you!!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `$.browser`? You're trying to detect the browser after all. That's what `$.browser` is for.

Comment: Why? There are very few cases where it really makes sense to do browser detection rather than feature detection. And if you don't want to use `$.browser`, if you [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) it tells you exactly where it gets its information (from `navigator.userAgent`).

Comment: The docs also say "We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery." about the `$.browser` property.

Comment: Way to go @Gromer , that is the reason I don't want to use jQuery.browser if I don't have to.

Comment: @DejoDekic But you were trying to detect Firefox, which is exactly what jQuery is recommending against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to your question: [How do I use JQuery.support to check if the browser is Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088934/how-do-i-use-jquery-support-to-check-if-the-browser-is-firefox)

You don't use support as a means to check what browser the user is using, but rather if the browser supports the DOM manipulation that you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do so without jquery. you can just check with an if statement as follows.

```
var ss = document.createElement('style');
if(ss.styleSheet)// checking if ss.styleSheet is supported.
{        
     ss.styleSheet.cssText = content;
}
```

If you want to check whether a property is supported or not, you can do by an if statement.

Comment: You're saying that only Firefox implements the `"styleSheet"` property?

Comment: no it does. i mean that if a property is supported by any browser you can easily check by an if stament.

Comment: We still don't know whether OP's issue can be resolved in that way, i.e. via feature-detection. It could be that his requirement to explicitly detect Firefox is justified.